# How do you unsubscribe from Yahoo’s "recent activity" spam? Their "unsubscribe" link is broken

Tags: yahoo

How do you unsubscribe from Yahoo's "recent activity" spam? They don't just spam on reply. They spam you on any up or down vote.

The email from them has an unsubscribe link but it is broken

Here is the HTML in the email that corresponds to unsubscribe

`<font face=\\\"arial\\\" style=\\\"font-size:11px;\\\">You received this email from Yahoo! because you posted on one or more of Yahoo!&#39;s sites.<a rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">Learn more<\/a>.If you do not want to receive further emails from Yahoo! regarding recent activity related to your posts, <span style=\\\"color:#3b3b3b;font-weight:bold;\\\">unsubscribe<\/span> by clicking <span style=\\\"color:#004f94;\\\"><a rel=\\\"nofollow\\\">here<\/a><\/span>.`

I've found within Yahoo settings there's an option "Update newsletter & marketing options". That was ticked. It's not a newsletter or offer but I've unticked that. That didn't stop it either.

Comment: @pnuts What on earth are you talking about. That link you give is to a question I asked about TWITTER. Here I am asking about Yahoo.

Comment: @pnuts I don't think you understand. If by general solution you mean like the general solution at that link - to click the unsubscribe link and see if there are options.  If you actually read my question you'll see the unsubscribe link is broken. I even mentioned this in the title.

Comment: @pnuts yeah users in general, if they don't have the problem I asked about. I cannot click the unsubscribe link because it isn't there. Do you understand that? Your comment is not relevant to solving the problem I asked about. Are you aware of that?